# Why Is Microsoft Able To Block Your Offline Play Legally?

Tags: licensing, eula

I bought a Mojang account a couple years ago and I lost both the email and credit card I bought it with so I’m unable to migrate meaning my account was suspended. I understand withholding online servers but how is it legal for them to completely stop me from running offline play when I have not broken their TOS.

That’s like if I buy some bread. Sure, the store (Mojang) has every right to change the bread buying experience, and to change the quality of their store because they own it, but how can they come to my home then steal the bread back after I purchase it because apparently they still “own” the license.

Answer (score 2):

Licensing is more like renting a car than buying bread.  It's their car; you have just paid to use it within constraints. It's not too surprising that losing everything that could prove you are the legitimate renter reduces what you can do with the car.